# How to get CTk label frame name?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, customtkinter

I need to get the name of the CTkFrame. That is, the root/frame information from a label.

This is the label. I need to get the 'loginPage' part.

```
signUpTrans = ctk.CTkLabel(master=loginPage, text='Sign up', text_color='light blue', font=font)
signUpTrans.place(relx=0.72, rely=0.9, anchor=CENTER)
```

So far I have tried:

```
print(signUpTrans.cget('master')
```

However that gives an error:

```
raise ValueError(f"'{attribute_name}' is not a supported argument. Look at the documentation for supported arguments.")
ValueError: 'master' is not a supported argument. Look at the documentation for supported arguments.
```

Comment: Try `signUpTrans.master` or `signUpTrans.winfo_parent()`.

Comment: Hi, I tried:
signUpTrans.master but it gave:
.!ctkframe 
and,
signUpTrans.winfor_parent gave: 
<bound method Misc.winfo_parent of <customtkinter.windows.widgets.ctk_label.CTkLabel object .!ctkframe.!ctklabel7>>

Comment: Note that it is `signUpTrans.winfo_parent()`.  Both `signUpTrans.master` and `signUpTrans.winfo_parent()` work for me.

Comment: what output are you getting? Once I included the parentheses, I get --> .!ctkframe

Comment: You should get the same output of `print(loginPage)`.  And what you get is correct if `loginPage` is the first instance of `CTkFrame` created.

Comment: Oh.. I get what you mean. However I want the name of the frame itself, that is 'loginPage'. If there was a way that given any label, I could be able to access the frame name, not the type, then that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: By "name", do you mean the variable that is associated with the widget? Widgets have an internal name, and when you create a widget it can be associated with one or several variables.

Comment: By 'name', I mean 'loginPage' which is associated with the variable signUpTrans. Essentially, just the name of the frame that I have assigned to the variable.